# Seeing whether the email used is in the database - PHP

Tags: php, sql

> I'm attempting to access my database to see if the email has been
>   used previously. All my attempts have failed. I can get the form to
>   enter the information into the database but that is it. I'm very new
>   to PHP so any help is appreciated.

```
 <?php
    require 'database.php';

    $message = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):



            $sql = "INSERT INTO noodles_gamification (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    if( $stmt->execute() ){;
            $message = 'Successfully created new user';

     }else {    
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM noodles_gamification WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error[] = 'email provided is already in use.';
        }

    } 
    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What issues are you having? Please update your question to include any errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if email is already exist or not before inserting new record to database Just modify your if condition some think like

```
<?php
        require 'database.php';

        $message = '';

        if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM noodles_gamification WHERE email = :email');
            $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(!empty($row['email'])){
                $error[] = 'email provided is already in use.';
            } else {



                $sql = "INSERT INTO noodles_gamification (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
        if( $stmt->execute() ){;
                $message = 'Successfully created new user';

         }
         }
         else {    

        } 
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, Appreciate it!

Comment: @SamAdams.if tis helped then please upvote and accept the answer